# Transform stream coming from S3 buckets

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

Here is my function to get the contents of multiple objects and merge in one single file:

```
const getAllObjectsInRegions = (config, keys) => {
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: `${config.metadata.s3.bucket}`,
        Key: key
      }
      const file = fs.createWriteStream('./out.txt')
      return s3.getObject(params)
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(file)
    })
```

basically the object that I read is just a json file. Do you have any idea how to transform the content of the object before writing to the file? I need to extract some property instead to write the entire file. Thank you

---

EDIT:

```
const getAllObjectsInRegions = (config, keys) => {

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      keys.forEach((key) => {
        const params = {
          Bucket: `${config.metadata.s3.bucket}`,
          Key: key
        }

        const readStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()

        readStream.on('data', (data) => {
          let playlist
          try {
            playlist = JSON.parse(data)
          } catch(err) {
            reject(err)
          }
          const slicedPlaylist = _.pick(playlist, ['contentKey', 'title', 'text' ])
          fs.writeFile('./out.txt', slicedPlaylist, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
            }
            resolve()
          })
        })
      })
    })

    return promise
  }
```

Comment: What about just buffering the data (e.g. adding a `data` event handler), `JSON.parse()` it, and then get at whatever property you need? Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @mscdex ok it sounds cool but then I need to save the content in the write stream. how can I save it? Inside the `data` event?

Comment: You want to save the original JSON content to `out.txt` or just the value you're pulling out?

Comment: Just the property I'm pulling out

Comment: In that case, you can just `file.end('' + someValue)`. Or you *could* just use `fs.writeFile()` since you're not really taking advantage of the streaming feature at that point.

Comment: Changed the functions but I get an error: unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: You will have to buffer *all* `data` event chunks until you see the readable stream's `end` event. Inside an `end` event handler is where you can safely (assuming the server didn't mess up the data somehow) parse the buffered data.